# Resuming current background activity on notification

Tags: java, android

My application contains multiple activities. I have implemented push notifications and also shown the notification in bar. My issue is, when i click on notification is take me to the specific activity that i has specified.

```
    Intent intent =new Intent(GcmService.this, MainActivity.class);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(GcmService.this, 0, intent, 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            getApplicationContext())
            .setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify((int) when, notificationBuilder.build());
```

I want if my activity is in background, and user click on the notification app resume the current activity that  is in background and show dialog box.
And if my application is closed. open the Launching activity and then show the dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to continue again when you click the notification(in this case your application still running on background) than you can using this method :
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/stopping.html

I've tried it and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can link your notification to a DispatcherActivity.
If you have open Activities on the backstack, finish the DispatcherActivity suddenly in `onCreate()`. If not, forward to your launching activity and finish the DispatcherActivity too.

To track your active activities on backstack use this [How to know Activity Count of my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429460/how-to-know-activity-count-of-my-application) suggestions.